# best way to change on input fields?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Am trying to create an extension that fill each input field(text,search,...) in any webpage with an icon when I click on it a drop down menu appears,
Just like Lazarus from recovery icon or the google search by voice icon,
I tried so many ways lately but nothing worked will :(
Am trying to find a way that is suitable for all fields whatever their shape or size

Comment: I tried to make image or button and wrap it with the input field in a div but it doesn't work like I want .. It appears beside the field but I want the icon  inside it without changing the field size or width

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elements = $('input[type=text], input[type=search], input[type=textarea]');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var input = elements[i];

            input.className = 'inputWithImge';
            var oImg = document.createElement('img');
            oImg.src = chrome.extension.getURL("list.png");
            oImg.className = 'img';

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {   
            $(".inputWithImge").after(oImg);
            $(".inputWithImge").each(function () {
                $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<divclass="imageInputWrapper"></div>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: .img
{
     vertical-align:middle !important; cursor:pointer !important;
}
.imageInputWrapper
{
    border:solid 1px #000 !important;display: inline-block !important;
}
.inputWithImge
{
 border:none !important; margin-right:5px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; height: auto !important; width: 100%  !important;
    
}